# Inserting into database from many different websites

Tags: asp.net, database, web-services, design-patterns

I have a customer enquiry management website with many different websites (on different servers) sending enquiries into it. Currently each website has a contact form on the page and the form creates a database connection with the SQL needed to insert into one central database.

This works but the problem is more and more websites are now sending in enquiries so I am duplicating this database code across many websites. If I needed to change something in the database, I would need to go through all websites and make the same update.

The enquiry management website is asp.net. The websites which insert enquiries into the database are a mixture of asp.net and php. I thought about just creating an insert page on the main website and each website posting to the that. The only problem with this is each website has its own website specific tasks to as well e.g. sending emails, adding to mail list. Inserting into the enquiry database is the only task which could be done externally/globally.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: How about creating a web service which will expose methods to do the operations on the database? All the other websites can then use these methods to perform the operations.

Answer (score 0):

To centralized your all the logic, you can implement Web Services. All you have to do is,just make a web service having all the business logic.

Then you can use this web service by adding the reference of it into your multiple web sites. It will be a one time job. Suppose,if you need to change some logic,then you can just change it in web service class. All the modifications will be applied to all websites which are consuming the same web service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can expose the operation through web service. if you are in .net platform, web api is a good way to implement that.

You can issue an ajax call to the web api on all the clients regardless the website platform (asp.net php...). If the form is in a similar/standard format, the javascript block can be centralize as well.